comparar huella con BD C# - SUPREMA
como puedo comparar 2 huellas la que coloco en el lector y la que tengo en la base de datos, ya guardo la huella en BD como tipo varbinary(max), y trato de buscar la huella a traves de un SELECT pero aunque exista y sea la que guarde no la encuentra, posiblemente por que la cadena es diferente a la almacenada ya que he identificado que aunque sea el mismo dedo por algun desplazamiento del dedo ya no coinciden, saben como evitar esto y puedan coincidir mi lector es marca SUPREMA minislim y asi hago mi validacion contra la BD


lstResultados.Items.Add("* COLOCA TU DEDO   " + DateTime.Now.ToString());
lstResultados.Refresh();
lstResultados.Update();


ufs_res = Scanner.ClearCaptureImageBuffer();
ufs_res = Scanner.CaptureSingleImage();
ufs_res = Scanner.Extract(Template1, out TemplateSize1, out EnrollQuality);
byte[] template0 = Template1;

Scanner.GetCaptureImageBuffer(out Bitmap btm1, out resolucion);
Picture.Image = new Bitmap(btm1, Picture.Size);
Picture.Refresh();
Picture.Update();               
              
                
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
Picture.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
BuscarRegistro(ms.GetBuffer());





public void BuscarRegistro(byte[] ms)
{
    string _connectionString = "Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=RegistraHuellas;integrated Security=true;";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
    {
        String query = "SELECT NombreCompleto from Registro where  Dactilar like '%@Huella%'";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Huella", ms);

            connection.Open();
            
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Existe");
                reader["NombreCompleto"].ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Existe");


            }
        }
    }
}




Sí, es posible obtener el nombre directamente a partir de la huella digital, pero necesitarás realizar la coincidencia de la huella con todas las plantillas almacenadas en la base de datos.
Así:
// Capturar y extraer la plantilla de huella digital
ufs_res = Scanner.CaptureSingleImage();
ufs_res = Scanner.Extract(Template1, out TemplateSize1, out EnrollQuality);

// Conexión a la base de datos
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT NombreCompleto, Dactilar FROM Registro", connection);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    bool encontrado = false;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        byte[] storedTemplate = (byte[])reader["Dactilar"];
        bool isMatch = Scanner.Match(Template1, storedTemplate, SecurityLevel.Normal);

        if (isMatch)
        {
            string nombre = reader["NombreCompleto"].ToString();
            MessageBox.Show("Huella coincide con: " + nombre);
            encontrado = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!encontrado)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No se encontró coincidencia");
    }
}

El código busca entre todas las plantillas en la base de datos y, si encuentra una coincidencia, te devuelve el nombre asociado.
Es más eficiente si tienes pocos registros, pero para bases de datos grandes, puede requerir optimización.

lo que intentaba realizar es que a través de la huella pudiera obtener el nombre de la coincidencia que obtuviera de la base de datos, crees que eso es posible? o tendría que tener un dato extra como un Id o un nombre de usuario y escanear la huella para poder obtener la coincidencia?

He editado el código, creo que ahora cumple con el requerimiento.

excelente, muchas gracias :)
